# Nginx returning 404 for index file when I try a HTTP request from Erlang

Tags: http, configuration, nginx, erlang

Using an updated version of this simple [urlget](http://www.erlang.org/article/8) module from the erlang site I can't seem to request an existing file from a HTTP server running nginx.

```
> urlget:direct("http://clientsideweb.net/index.html"). 
Here connect:"clientsideweb.net" 80
{ok,{"http://clientsideweb.net/index.html",
     {"HTTP/1.1",404,"Not Found"},
     [{"Connection","close"},
      {"Content-Length","168"},
      {"Content-Type","text/html"},
      {"Date","Sun, 03 Mar 2013 12:18:05 GMT"},
      {"Server","nginx/1.2.5"}],
     "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.2.5</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"}}
```

If you browse to the address manually you get the index.html file as normal. I think maybe nginx may have some inbuilt security config that restricts based on http headers? Anyone know for sure? I tried adding a chrome-like User Agent header string but it returned a 404 with additional comments on something about 'padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page'

Comment: *If you browse to the address manually you get the index.html file as normal.* I can't. I see 404 in my firefox. Maybe it's just your browser cache.

Comment: I also get a 404 not found

Comment: well seen - edited question code with correct url, still same problem described.